# Check searchable field of an entity based on indexing

Tags: hibernate-search

I have an entity defined as following.

```
public class Deal {
    @Id
    @DocumentId
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "ADVERTISER_NAME")
    private String advertiserName;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "BRAND_NAME")
    private String brandName;

    //other fields and getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

If I want to search on all searchable fields, I can do something like the following, which demonstrates the usage of onField, onFields and andFields.

```
Query luceneQuery1 = mythQB
    .simpleQueryString()
    .onFields("name", "history", "description")
    .matching("teststring")
    .createQuery();


Query luceneQuery2 = mythQB
    .simpleQueryString()
    .onField("name")
        .boostedTo(5f)
    .andFields("advertiserName", "brandName")
        .boostedTo(2f)
    .withAndAsDefaultOperator()
    .matching("teststring")
    .createQuery();
```

If I add Index.NO to @Field(making an entity field not searchable),for example, change the annotation of brandName to @Field(index = Index.NO), now I only have two searchable fields: name and advertiserName, if we don't consider id. In this case, the example query above will throw runtime exception because it tries to search on brandName that is not searchable.

I've tried something like the following to dynamically get the full list of searchable fields based on whether a field has annotation or not. But this won't work if the index is Index.NO.

My question is that is there a way to dynamically get the full list of searchable fields based on the actual index value?

```
    protected String[] getSearchableFields() {
        List<String> fields = Lists.newArrayList();
        Class<?> c = clazz;
        while (c != null) {
            for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field.class) 
                    || field.isAnnotationPresent(org.hibernate.search.annotations.Fields.class)) {

                    if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
                        fields.add(field.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
            c = c.getSuperclass();
        }
        return fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a metadata API in Hibernate Search.

```
FullTextSession ftSession = ...;
IndexedTypeDescriptor indexedType = ftSession.getSessionFactory().getIndexedTypeDescriptor(clazz);
for (PropertyDescriptor property : indexedType.getIndexedProperties()) {
    for (FieldDescriptor field : property.getIndexedFields()) {
        if (field.getIndex() == Index.YES) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

See [this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_metadata_api) for more information.

There are a few limitations, like not being able to "see" the extra fields contributed by custom bridges. But it works well apart from that.